# How can i listen single port but different ip addresses with c#

Tags: c#, .net-core, tcpclient

I've tcp/ip devices running on same network. They have ip addresses like '192.168.1.100:5600', '192.168.1.101:5600'. The question is how can i listen all devices with single instance. UDP style is running on this scenerio. But i can't handle with tcp communication. My code running with specific ip addresses. Here is my code

```
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        client.Connect(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.185"), 11010);
        while (true)
        {
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            var data = new Byte[256];
            String responseData = String.Empty;
            Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
            responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
            if (responseData.Substring(0, 3) == "%CD")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your code does not `"listen"`. You are connecting to a host as a client.  TcpClient can only be used to make a single connection to s single host. If you reverse roles (use TcpListener instead), you can listen on port 5600 and have the other computers connect to your listener.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using TCP to communicate with your devices, then you cannot read data from all devices using single socket instance. You need to create socket between two end points, one is your device and other is your application. Number of devices you want to access in you application, those many sockets you need to create and listen on them.

Other approach that I can think is, instead your application connecting to each device, device can connect to you central server/service. Devices then can push their data to server application. In both the case you need same number of sockets to be created.

Comment: You do not need to listen on multiple sockets. You can create a single TcpListener which will create a socket for you for each incoming connection.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-cc/  Here is the sample code, with steps required at server side and client side mentioned.